# Story beats for woman masquerading as a man

Tags: structure

I am writing a story that uses the woman masquerading as a sailor trope.  I have read a few and they seem to have similar beats.  But I am having a hard time teasing them out from the story.  I am not sure I am hitting sufficiently on the try/fail cycle.  Here are some beats that I could figure out and have incorporated, but I feel like I am missing some.

- Persona Created
- Shipboard (Threshold)
- Learning the ropes (mentors and try fail)
- ...
- Faking the swagger
- Accidental reveal
- Blackmail identity
- Purposeful reveal
- Secret romance
- ...
- Reveal
- Denouncement
- Coda

Anything else I am missing?

Comment: I know you're just asking for the beats of that trope, but when I read it I think: Why does she masquerade as a man? To me, this is just not interesting. It will become interesting, if that woman has a personality, and a goal derived from that personality, and if this trope is played against that. E.g. if she has to masquerade to escape being killed by whoever, or if at least she wants to understand what it is like to be a man. Anything really, because a pure trope is flat. And once you have stakes and a plot, that will create its own beats.

Comment: @what ^^That's an excellent comment. I think you should make that an answer.

Comment: But it does not answer the question, and OP might know all that I wrote in my comment and just want to focus on the trope for reasons of his own.

Comment: This is basically asking what to write, which is off-topic here. Can anyone think of a way to make this a more answerable question?

Comment: So the heroes journey of the woman masquerading as a man to be a sailor/soldier seems to be pretty consistent from story to story.  Partially I am looking for what are the beats of the story that I missed.  Partially so that I don't accidentally walk the trope and make it paint by numbers.

Comment: Questions about storytelling tools *are* on topic here, but I'm torn. I've [opened a discussion about this question on our meta site](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/944/story-beats-question-is-it-on-topic-here).

Comment: As per the [meta discussion](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/q/944/26) mentioned above, I'm closing this question.